# Proof that Every Differentiable Manifold is Paracompact in Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

My question is why we can choose a enumerable subcollection of a given enumerable basis, such that every elemento of this subcollection has compact closure.

In other words, on the following lemma, from Frank Warner' Foundations of Differentiable Manifold and Lie Groups

[image]

How can we choose the

> subcollection consisting of basic sets with compact closures

The fact that X is compact and locally compact is only used after, therefore, I suppose is not necessary for this choice.

If it's a fact from basic topology, I would appreciate a reference for such fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you *do* need local compactness here. Take your countable basis $\mathcal B$. Whenever $p \in U$ with $U$ open there is a compact neighborhood $p \in K \subseteq U$. Because $\mathcal B$ is a basis, you can take $p \in O \subseteq K$ with $O \in \mathcal B$.

In a Hausdorff space, necessarily $K$ is closed and so the closure of $O$ is compact (a closed subset of a compact).